# Universal E-catalog pattern

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce

I have question about this [pdf](http://hillside.net/plop/2006/Papers/ACM_Version/Universal_E-Catalog_Pattern.pdf). What is ATT_TYPE in the ATTRIBUTE Table in figure 1? Firstly, I assumed that it contains database field type (like integer, varchar and so on..). But the type of ATT_TYPE field is integer. It can`t contain string like '*varchar*'.

Comment: I think that you are right but there is mapping and these integers are "constants", like 1 = integer, 2 = varchar etc. I've seen similar design, it's nothing unusual.

Comment: Thank you very much. We fixed the problem as you think :) I appreciate your attention